# How to STRING REPLACE that ignores the string inside of another string

Tags: php, str-replace

**Here is the TLDR version of my question:** 
Is there any way to do a str_replace on the string "q11-q2" where performing str_replace("q1","45", "q11-q2") doesn't replace the "q1" part of "q11"?

**More Details**
I am working on a financial calculator where users input financial data and we spit out results. For reason I won't get into, we don't write the formulas as code, we need to keep the formulas in a table as strings. For example, the table has columns that look like:

        *((q2/4)*0.25)*49 

        q10/(q2/4)*

I need to insert the answers to question 1 thru 12 into the formula where it says q1,q2,...q10,q11,q12 respectively. To do this I am doing:

```
$query= ///here i'd select each formula
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
     $formula=$row['formula']; ///would pull 
     for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) { //loop thru every answer and replace the Q version.
            $answer= $_POST['answer_'.$x]; ///answer to this question
            $formula=str_replace("q".$x, $answer, $formula);
      } //loop thru every answer and replace the Q version.
endwhile;
```

The problem is when we're at $x=1 it is replacing the q1 in the formula that is part of "q10", "q11", and "q12"

Comment: Can you edit the formulas? Give the variables a unique wrapper like `({q1}/2)` so you can replace using `"{q".$x."}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps use `preg_replace` with a negative lookahead pattern like `q1(?!\d)`, meaning "q1" not followed by another digit character.

```
preg_replace("#q1(?!\d)#","45", "q11-q2-q1-q1");
# q11-q2-45-45
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can loop backwards:

```
 for ($x = 12; $x > 1; $x--) { //loop thru every answer and replace the Q version.
        $answer= $_POST['answer_'.$x]; ///answer to this question
        $formula=str_replace("q".$x, $answer, $formula);
  } //loop thru every answer and replace the Q version.
```

This way `Q11` is modified before `Q1`.